# Running npm scripts parallelly utilizing full processor capacity

Tags: performance, npm, webpack, build, frontend

I am running 7 npm commands parallelly using npm-run-all.

Running each command individually takes around 3 minutes. However, when I am running all the commands parallelly, it is taking 8 minutes and some times more than that.

How to execute these npm scripts parallelly utilizing all the processor cores?

I tried using concurrently as well. Also, I am thinking of running a shell script. However, this has to work in windows also.

Comment: I've used `glob-exec` to run things in parallel and it has helped me chop a significant amount of time off of my builds on both Linux and Windows for a project I maintain: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-build-release-tasks/blob/master/package.json#L16

Comment: so, if I have two npm scripts "cmd1" and "cmd2", then should I create the glob-exec command like "glob-exec --parallel --foreach \"npm run cmd1\" -- \"npm run cmd2\"" ?

Comment: No glob-exec takes one or more files on disk to operate on. It will run a command for each of the files on disk. You may be looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all instead.

Comment: I already tried npm-run-all and concurrently like I mentioned in my question. It runs parallelly, but, still time not reduced much

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `worker-farm` and `parallel-webpack` or `concurrently`

https://blog.box.com/blog/how-we-improved-webpack-build-performance-95
https://github.com/rvagg/node-worker-farm 
https://github.com/trivago/parallel-webpack 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

I am not expert, just putting thoughts together, maybe some expert can comment upon

Comment: Thanks Akshay. It was helpful. I think like jessehouwing mentioned below, 7 tasks in parallel seems like an overkill. Even if tasks are running parallelly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run multiple npm commands in parallel you can use `npm-run-all`. It installs into your project and is available after your dependencies have been restored (unless of course, you install it globally).

If you want to run a command against multiple files in parallel you can use `glob-exec`. You supply it with a glob pattern to match one or more files and glob-exec will execute the command against each file.

Both packages have the option to run in parallel or in sequence. I've used the latter to shave multiple minutes off of my build times

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, I am already trying with npm-run-all package. I also tried with concurrently. These all runs parallelly. But, when 7 commands are running simultaneously, it still has an impact which I am trying to reduce

Comment: Are you sure CPU is your current bottleneck? 7 tasks in parallel can put a lot of stress on your IO.

Comment: I guess you are right. It is utilizing the CPU 100%. But, still, 7 tasks seems too much to be done parallelly at a single go.

Comment: If the cpu is at 100%, then the parallelization is doing its job.